# how to read y4m video(get the frames) file in matlab

Tags: matlab, video

I want to read the video file which is in y4m format into matlab. I want the frames to process. please someone help me i need it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Matlab VideoUtils toolbox:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/videoutils/

Answer (score 0):

The Matlab Robotics Toolbox contains a class YUV (file YUV.m) that is used to get images from a YUV4MPEG2 file which has the .y4m extension.

You can also look here:

[How to read yuv videos in matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19074293/how-to-read-yuv-videos-in-matlab)