# How to read yuv videos in matlab?

Tags: matlab, video-processing, yuv

I have a yuv video and I have to read it in Matlab for video processing. I have used mmreader but it appears that it only accepts avi and mpg files. VideoReader is not available in my version of Matlab and I don't think it supports yuv file extension.

Answer (score 1):

do these code solve your problems?

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6318-convert-yuv-cif-420-video-file-to-image-files

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11252-yuv-file-to-matlab-movie

Comment: Yes! I think this is just what I need! Do you know how to use the program in the first link? I have some questions :)

Comment: How do you find the end of the video. The 4th parameter in the `loadYuvImage` function is the frame number. How do you know all the frames have ended ?