# Split an uncompressed video into segments with ffmpeg on MatLab?

Tags: matlab, video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I have a video sequence(format Y4M) and I want to split it into sevral segment with the same GoP size.
GoP = 8;
How can I do that in MatLab using FFMPEG ?

Comment: So you want every segment to be 8 frames long? Sorry, I'm not that familiar with your terminology.

Comment: Yes exactly @Cecilia.

Comment: Any particular reason you want to use FFMPEG? Matlab has other methods for loading and processing video.

Comment: There is not, I just didn't  know that or know how to use them. @Cecilia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One standard way of representing video in Matlab is a 4D matrix. The dimensions are height x width x color channels x frames. Once you have the matrix, it is easy to take time slices by specifying the range of frames that you would like.

For example, you can grab 8 frames at a time in a for-loop

```
%Loads video as 4D matrix
v = VideoReader('xylophone.mp4');
while hasFrame(v)
    video = cat(4, video, readFrame(v));
end

%iterate over the length of the movie with step size of 8
for i=1:8:size(video, 4)-8 
    video_slice = video(:,:,:,i:i+7); %get the next 8 frames

    % do something with the 8 frames here

    % each frame is a slice across the 4th dimension
    frame1 = video_slice(:,:,:,1);
end

%play movie
implay(video)
```

The other most common way of representing video is in a structure array. You can index a structure array with a range of values to slice 8 frames. The actual frame values in my example are stored in the structure element `cdata`. Depending on your structure the element might have a different name; look for an element with a 3d matrix value.

```
% Loads video as structure
load mri
video = immovie(D,map);
%iterate over the length of the movie with step size of 8
for i=1:8:size(video, 4)-8 
    video_slice = video(i:i+7); %get the next 8 frames

    % do something with the 8 frames here

    % to access the frame values use cdata
    frame1 = video_slice(1).cdata
end

%play movie
implay(video)
```

The tricky part is your video format. Y4M is not supported by Matlab's [`VideoReader`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.html) which is the most common way to load video. It is also not supported by the [`FFmpeg Toolbox`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42296-ffmpeg-toolbox) which only provides a few media formats (MP3, AAC, mpeg4, x264, animated GIF).

There are a couple other questions that look for solutions to this problem including

1. [how to read y4m video(get the frames) file in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798461/how-to-read-y4m-videoget-the-frames-file-in-matlab)
2. [How to read yuv videos in matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19074293/how-to-read-yuv-videos-in-matlab)

I would also check on [the Matlab File Exchange](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/50690-yuv4mpeg-reader), but  I don't have personal experience with any of these methods.

Comment: I will try it and see if it solve the main prblm. Thanks @cecilia

Comment: Another question id I may, why a 4D matrix ?

Comment: Matlab is built around matrices, so matrices seem like a natural choice since the elements (pixels) of a video are  homogeneous, dense, and represented by numbers.

Comment: I'm back to you, I could read the Y4M file and got a struct of all the frames. If I want to do as you said above, how can I do that with what I have ?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a struct array example.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answer and your time, I really appreciate it.